# Bad title on tag wiki pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki

Tag wiki pages [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info) currently have `'StackOverflow.Models.Tag'` instead of the tag name in the title.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Maybe the developer wanted to tag some models? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fix will be deployed shortly, apologies, I blame waffles.

Comment: I do too.... :)